# Why Does Torture Exist?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, brahman

please give me your best explanation from a spiritual point of view (from Brahman's point of view). I am not talking about what can be called "meaningful pain." I am speaking of meaningless pain, meaningless suffering - torture for the sake of torture. Why does it exist?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Brahman's point of view'?

Comment: And 'meaningful pain'?

Comment: Torture, sufferings, evils, bad, all exist because lack of Jnana... Jnana destroys all!

Comment: @Partha, by Brahman's point of view, I mean "God's" point of view. I understand that we are aspects of God. But I don't understand why torture exists? By "meaningful pain," I mean pain that can help us grow. What I mean is that I see the value of pain and suffering, but only to a degree. I don't see it's value when pain is pushed to such an extreme that it becomes torture.

Comment: @ss3592 okay.but who u expect here to know God's point of view?

Comment: Nirguna Brahman, Brahman without attributes, does not experience anything of the sensual universe. It is not aware of the sensual universe. It is only those who are within the sensual universe that are aware of, and experience pleasure and pain. "Why" only exists within the sensual universe. Beyond the sensual universe there is no 'why'.